# sql syntax error execute query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, syntax

I'm trying to run this query oh php my admin MySQL ,but it does not work.

```
CREATE TABLE blog
(
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
title TEXT UNIQUE, 
body TEXT,
url TEXT UNIQUE
);
```

I can not understand where I'm wrong.

Error: #1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'title' used in key specification without a key length

Comment: Perfect, now say: #1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'title' used in key specification without a key length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error happens because you're trying to set an *index* with fields of type TEXT (or BLOB). Mysql can't handle that. You should specify a lenght for those fields, but that can't be done, so I think you must use VARCHAR for *title* and *url* fields, because TEXT is for very long fields.

If you use VARCHAR(with a length) you will be able to use them in some indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Yeap, Eduardo is right, you should try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE blog
(
 id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 title VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
 body TEXT NOT NULL,
 url VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```